# Angular Subject Multiple unwanted subscriptions talking between components

Tags: angular, subject

I am learning about Subject and how to use it to talk between components.

This is my setup

**message-bus.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessageBusService {
  private subject: Subject<any>;

  constructor() {
   this.subject = new Subject<any>();
  }

  sendMessage(type: string, data?: any) {
    this.subject.next({ type, data });
  }

  clearMessage() {
    this.subject.next();
  }

  getMessage(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

Then I have a **type.component.ts** that I am currently only using to click a button in the UI and open a modal.

```
  constructor(
    private contentTypeService: ContentTypeService,
    private messageBusService: MessageBusService,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
  ) {
    this.contentTypes = new MatTableDataSource([]);
    this.initSubscriptions();
    this.contentTypes.sort = this.sort;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadContentTypes();
  }

  sortData() {
    this.contentTypes.sort = this.sort;
  }

  private initSubscriptions() {
    this.subscriptions = [
      this.messageBusService
        .getMessage()
        .subscribe(message => {
          if (!message) return;

          if (message.type == SEARCH_VALUE_CHANGED) {
            this.contentTypes.filter = message.data.trim().toLowerCase();
          } else if (message.type == PAGE_HEADER_CREATE_CLICKED) {
            this.openCreateModal();
          }
        })
    ]
  }

  openCreateModal() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ContentTypeModalComponent, {
      data: {
        title: 'Content Type',
      },
      width: '550px',
      // height: '530px',
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(`Dialog result: ${result}`);
    });
  }
```

My Modal is made of a basic reusable modal that only defines the header and footer and leaves open what to put in the body via .
So to keep things shorter I will only add here the component specific modal that reports back to my type.component.ts which is where I want to then do something with the result of what is in the modal.

**conten_type-modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import * as _ from 'lodash';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { MessageBusService } from '../../../shared/services/message-bus.service';
import { MODAL_CREATE_CLICKED, MODAL_CANCEL_CLICKED, MODAL_CLOSE_CLICKED } from '../../../shared/constants/modal-events';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'content_type-modal',
  templateUrl: './content_type-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content_type-modal.component.scss']
})
export class ContentTypeModalComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup;
  subscriptions: Subscription[];//Use array if multiple subs

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data,
    private messageBusService: MessageBusService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ContentTypeModalComponent>,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      name: [null, Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(40)])],
      weightToVolumeRatio: [null, Validators.min(0)],
    });

    this.subscriptions = [
      this.messageBusService
        .getMessage()
        .subscribe(message => {
          if (!message) return;
          console.log("got ", message);
          if (message.type === MODAL_CREATE_CLICKED) {
            this.save();
          } else if (message.type === MODAL_CLOSE_CLICKED) {
            this.closeModal();
          }
        })
    ]
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  save() {
    console.log(this.form.value);
    this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // unsubscribe to any subscriptions ensure no memory leaks
    // this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => subscription.unsubscribe());
  } 

  closeModal() {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }
}
```

Now I have realized it might not be a good idea to have a message bus where everything run on indiscriminately so you are subscribed to more than you might care, but i will split it later.

My issue is that when I click to open the modal, then say I cancel(abort) and thereby close the modal, then I open it again, enter some info and then press create (save) then my main component  type.component.ts get the subscription call back with the message type MODAL_CREATE_CLICKED twice (or x number of times you open and close the dialog).

```
if (message.type === MODAL_CREATE_CLICKED) {
            this.save();
          }
```

Can someone explain me why it might be? i am quite confused ...

Comment: hi, that happen in the shared modal that I didn't include. it sends the "create" , "cancel"  and "close" action of the modal.

Comment: it seems to work now with always including ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscriptions.forEach(subscription => subscription.unsubscribe());
  }

Comment: I thought I had already included it but and still wasn't working but I might have been wrong :/

Answer (score 0):

isnt there missing code here?

where are you doing `this.messageBusService.sendMessage(type: string, data?: any)` with this, any observer that is initialised with the subject should be called.

If this is the entire code. you perhaps are getting the initial subject value.

The reason you keep getting an increase of messages, is because you are not closing / ending the connections between observers and subject.

example:

modal_instance_1
this initialises a subscription.

you close the modal, but the subscription is still in memory.

modal_instance_2
this initialises another subscription.

but you still have the first subscription available.

rule of thumb when using rxjs observables etc, is to decide how long you would like that subscription to be available.

examples:
Once the subject emits the first value, close the connection.

```
  this.messageBusService.getMessage()
    .pipe(take(1)) // can be x amount of times.
    .subscribe(message => {
      ...    
    })
```

Once the component is destroyed close the connection.

```
  private _destroy$: Subject<any> = new Subject()

  constructor() {}

  ...

  this.messageBusService.getMessage()
    .pipe(takeUntil(this._destroy$) // can be x amount of times.
    .subscribe(message => {
      ...    
    })

  ...

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._destroy$.next()
    this._destroy$.complete()
  }
```

hope this helps somewhat :)